# Extracting 2nd element from multiple sub-lists with stepping

Tags: python, list, slice

Originally I had a list of coordinates for drawing a 'zig-zag' pattern in the form:

```
[10,10,20,20,30,10,40,20]
```

I wanted to check that all of the 'top' values of the y-coordinate were the same so that the pattern would work. I extracted them by the following:

```
a_vals = coords[1::4]
```

Which gave me the new list I was looking for of all elements being 10. I also repeated this to check that each second coordinate after had the y-part of 20.

---

However, now the coordinates have been split into sub-lists, in which I still need to extract them all into a new list (all values being 10 and then 20 for the later check):

```
[[10,10],[20,20],[30,10],[40,20]]
```

From what I've gathered it should be possible to slice it, but I'm not quite too sure of how to do it with sub-lists involved, bearing in mind it will have to step to the next sub-list to extract the value.

Comment: Your actual data is of the form [x, y, x, y, ...]?

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes exactly, and then I need to change it so the program will accept [[x,y],[x,y],...] and extract the elements I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for this , along with slicing your list -

```
a_vals = [y for x,y in coords[::2]]
```

This would get you all the *top* coordinate y values for , for the other y values , you can simply change the slicing in the above to `coords[1::2]` .

Demo -

```
>>> coords = [[10,10],[20,20],[30,10],[40,20]]
>>> a_vals = [y for x,y in coords[::2]]
>>> a_vals
[10, 10]
>>> b_vals = [y for x,y in coords[1::2]]
>>> b_vals
[20, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [10,10,20,20,30,10,40,20] 
>>> L1 = [x for x in L[::2]] # First Elements
>>> L1
[10, 20, 30, 40]
>>> L2 = [x for x in L[1::2]] # Second Elements
>>> L2
[10, 20, 10, 20]
>>> [[x, y] for x, y in zip(L1, L2)] # Group Them
[[10, 10], [20, 20], [30, 10], [40, 20]]
```